# Merging word-documents using DocumentFormat.OpenXml(c#)

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is there any way to make merging 2 word-documents using library `DocumentFormat.OpenXML`, considering the mode of MS Word "Track Changes".
 Or maybe it's possible using another library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standart api of MS Word

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document worddoc;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range _range;              
    object file = "1.doc";
    wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    worddoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file); 
    _range = worddoc.Content;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = _range; 
    rng.Start = rng.End;
    rng.InsertFile("2.doc");
```

**EDIT**

And read this [Merging-Word-Documents](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7582/Merging-Word-Documents-with-C)

**EDIT2**

so try this

```
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
    using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
    ....
    public byte[] OpenAndCombine(List<string> FileNames)
    {
        List<byte[]> documents = new List<byte[]>();
        foreach (string _FileName in FileNames)               
                documents.Add(File.ReadAllBytes(_FileName));

        MemoryStream mainStream = new MemoryStream();

        mainStream.Write(documents[0], 0, documents[0].Length);
        mainStream.Position = 0;

        int pointer = 1;
        byte[] ret;
            using (WordprocessingDocument mainDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mainStream, true))
            {

                XElement newBody = XElement.Parse(mainDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OuterXml);

                for (pointer = 1; pointer < documents.Count; pointer++)
                {
                    WordprocessingDocument tempDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(new MemoryStream(documents[pointer]), true);
                    XElement tempBody = XElement.Parse(tempDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OuterXml);

                    newBody.Add(tempBody);
                    mainDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body(newBody.ToString());
                    mainDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    mainDocument.Package.Flush();
                }
            }
            ret = mainStream.ToArray();
            mainStream.Close();
            mainStream.Dispose();
        return (ret);
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid using library Interop

Comment: And i understand why ))) But you asked "possible using another library?"

Comment: Yes, I posed the question is not entirely accurate))
Is there any other library using which it can be done? (excluding the library Interop)  If this is the only way - I am very saddened by this :(

Comment: I get misprint (Files -> FileNames)